# Seq[String, Int] to Seq[Int] in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections, seq

My problem is to create suffix array for a given string.
So far I've taken the tails of the string paired them with indexes and sorted them by strings.
I need to drop the string part of the tuple so I can return `Seq[Int]`, but I don't know how to do that.

This is what I tried to do:

```
def suffixArray(s: String): Seq[Int] = s.tails.zipWithIndex.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply map it:

```
seq.map(_._2)
```

or using pattern matching:

```
seq.map { case(s, i) -> i }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
def suffixArray(s: String): Seq[Int] = s.tails.zipWithIndex.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```